# Left align a group of tables so that they all appear on the same line

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="horizontal-scroller">
        <table class="float-left">
            <tr>
                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="float-left">
            <tr>
                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="float-left">
            <tr>
                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

And CSS:

```
.float-left {
  float: left;
}

.horizontal-scroller {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

I am trying to achive the effect where all three tables appear on the same row no matter the size of the containing div.  This example works well when the page is wide enough to fit them.  But when I shrink the size of the page the tables start to wrap.  I don't want this to happen.  Instead I want a horizontal scrollbar to appear on the div so that the user can scroll to see them.  How can I achieve this?

Plunker example: https://plnkr.co/edit/ffSvoraDERVgdi1RFF31?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: flex` on the parent will put it in a flex `row`

```css
/* Styles go here */

.horizontal-scroller {
    overflow-x: auto;
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-scroller">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by wrapping each table in a `<div>` and using a combination of `display: inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap`.

Your HTML could look something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then the CSS could do the following:

```
.wrapper {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is the full example: https://jsfiddle.net/xzd0dqhk/

Comment: You don't need the wrapper classes. Just set the table elements themselves to inline-block, and add the whitespace nowrap to horizontal-scroller class. https://plnkr.co/edit/Xh8zXzpFcBOjA273uDA8?p=preview

Comment: @A.Sharma: fair point. I sometimes forget that `display: table` doesn't really do much, all the real table functionality is handled by the `<tr>` and `<td>`